# How to add audit for logout with Jhipster generated code?

Tags: spring, jhipster, audit-logging

I debugged how audit is getting added into system for successful login and figured out that **CustomAuditEventRepository.auditEventRepository().add(AuditEvent event)** is getting invoked using **aop**. Is there any documentation how to add audits for any custom actions?

Answer (score 11):

I was able to achieve the above thing with the following code.

- **Created class that could publish audit event.**

```java
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEvent;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.listener.AuditApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisherAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AuditEventPublisher implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware  {
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(
            ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void publish(AuditEvent event) {
        if (this.publisher != null)
            this.publisher.publishEvent(new AuditApplicationEvent(event));
    }
}
```

- **Inject AuditEventPublisher where you need it and call publish with audit event to be inserted to db**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserXAuthTokenController {

    @Inject
    private AuditEventPublisher auditPublisher;

.....
.....

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout",
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Timed
    public void logout(@RequestParam String authToken) {
        String principal = tokenProvider.getUserNameFromToken(authToken);
        AuditEvent event = new AuditEvent(principal, "LOGOUT_START", new HashMap<String, Object>());
        auditPublisher.publish(event);
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }

}
```